# How I can know if I have headphones connected to my computer? HTML5 + JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

How I can know if I have headphones connected to my computer? My goal is to get it using HTML5 + JavaScript.

On the next page shows all audio output devices, but there is no way of knowing if the active device is a headphonet or not. And in Firefox it doesn't work!

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/

All I want to know is if I have headphones connected with HTML5 and JavaScript.

Comment: You can't. Even if you could see that a mini-jack is plugged into the device, you couldn't tell for sure it's headphones, and I'll not mention all the different kind of bluetooth devices that can be set as audio output. Well, one way would be `window.confirm('do you have your headphones plugged in ?')`

Comment: You seem to have a consistency for asking really bad questions that seem to get positive responses. Please check the FAQs on how to ask good questions, and please stop getting your friends to upvote your bad questions. Seriously, why does this have 2 upvotes?? You have shown no research effort whatsoever

Comment: @musefan  Out of curiosity, have you any good tips on what he would need to do, to make his question better.  Looking here -> http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  he seems to have most bases covered, apart from maybe `Help others reproduce the problem`  but I assume that might be a little bit more tricky in this case.

Comment: @Keith: Well, this question is basically a "do it for me question" which never goes down well. There is no research effort shown to try to solve the problem by themselves. Also, it says *something* doesn't work in Firefox, which implies *something* works in other browsers... what is that something?

Answer (score 2):

As of today (2019 march) there is no realiable, cross-browser built-in tool to detect whether a user has headphones plugged in. While you theoretically can get audio output destination device and test it for phrases like `headset`, `earphones` etc, in a typical case it rather provides you with driver's name, which **usually** doesn't change when user plugs his earphones in. The *usually* part makes this approach useless.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way using any existing API, but one way could be to send a sound out while checking if the microphone picks it up.

This would be a real test for echo, you could use some "welcome" sound and some FFT code to "parse" microphone input and see if the sound you are sending is re-entering the microphone. However it would require quite some fine tuning to be reliable, and will still not catch people with low volume on the speakers or catch people with too loud headphones .. even if, in that case, since they are producing echo, catching them is probably the right thing to do.

I can't remember which conferencing software was actually doing this setup step emitting a melody and checking the feedback (maybe it was Skype early versions?), but it's doable in modern browsers.