# Detect If Headset is connected or not in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angular, webrtc

I want to check if the microphone and headset is connected or not. I've successfully detected if microphone is connected or not by below code.

```
 var mic = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
    mic.then(function () {
        alert("Mic connected")
    }).catch(function (err) {
        alert("Please Connect Your Mic");
    })
```

Now I want to do the same with the headset but I cannot find any solution for this. Can someone help on how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't the feedback you get now already for the headset as well? [getUserMedia documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) shows no distinction between any audio device. Also the `.getUserMedia({ audio: true });` only request permission to use it, it says nothing about connected devices to begin with. You need to look at [MediaDevices.enumerateDevices()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices)

Comment: No it does not give for the headset it is just for microphone detection. And MediaDevices.enumeratedDevices() returns five audio output devices, but I want to get info about my headsets only

Comment: Again `.getUserMedia({ audio: true });` only reports that you have access to _any_ audio device on the system, it does not differentiate between speakers, headset, microphone, whatever. Using the list from `MediaDevices.enumeratedDevices()` you can select the headset or microphone. Of course this is different per system or even user. If you are lucky the name has _headset_ in it, but most likely it will not (this might be assignable on system level).

Comment: yes those list are different for every system so I am not using it, and .getUserMedia({ audio: true }); I don't know for me it only reports about the microphones.

Comment: There really is no way to avoid using `MediaDevices.enumeratedDevices()` to solve this. And the reason you only see the microphones using `getUserMedia({ audio: true });` is because you have default access to use the speakers/headset (or any output device). This can in theory be different as well so a system could have ask for permission to use those too, although I don't think this is implemented at all.

Comment: okay, I got your point, but I don't see a clear way to work with this now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How I can know if I have headphones connected to my computer? HTML5 + JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40106777/how-i-can-know-if-i-have-headphones-connected-to-my-computer-html5-javascript)

Comment: @Fullslack.dev there is no solution to this it says, there is no possible ways as of now to detect the headphones....

Comment: @Fullslack.dev btw thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

you can add an event listener for device change:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.addEventListener('devicechange', () => {
  // you need to label the device if it is a headset or not.
});
```

Chekout [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices) reference for more information

Comment: this will only work if device gets changes right? for eg. If I remove any of my input/output device, then it will work. I want to to check it wiihtout any change

Comment: also enumerated device shows 5 audio output devices so I want to check for my headset specifically